# Como se quita el panel de informacion de visual estudio

Tags: visual-studio

llevo unos meses programando y siempre me aparece este panel tan molesto que te dice que es la palabra o que hace , sabéis como se quita?.
he buscado información por Google pero no encuentro nada
[image]

Comment: visual studio o visual stuido code?

Comment: visual estudio code

Comment: visual studio code es un editor de texto con capacidades de ide. Si te muestra eso, es porque instalaste un plugin (una extension) que hace eso.. buscalo, desactivalo y listo....